# Add option to hide Products menu

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, new-nav, products-menu

Other than using a monkey patch, I'd like an option to hide the new Products menu. I currently have my left side navigation collapsed. Perhaps it could be folded into there.

Comment: I think you already know no dev time will be spent on this ;)

Comment: @Stijn doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Yes, this would be appreciated, at least for those of us who *already are the product*.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for those of us who can't see it (yet)? Edit - NVM, it's just on Main. Userscripts can target it at `.js-gps-track.-marketing-link`.

Comment: Also probably related/included in the same rollout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWIwj.png

Comment: My updated [No More Jobs!](https://stackapps.com/q/8032/54539) script now hides the Products menu.

Comment: Why is the banner @TylerH mentioned put over the *answer* field and not on the *Ask Question* page?

Comment: My [ReduceClutter userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js) has been updated to hide the Products menu.